# Clear Datasource, reloadData, Cells still have old info?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

#### After wiping the datasource and reloadData, tableviewcells still show old information.

I'm creating a tableview that shows search results for users in a database.

When I perform a search, the datasource is populated and users are added in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For each cell that is created, an associating profile photo and button are created and added to the current cell.

I've got a method I'm using just for testing, which clears the datasource and reloads all the cells

```
- (IBAction)cleardaTables:(id)sender {
    [_dataSource removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If I clear my search with that button, and search something else, or display a placeholder cell that says "search for a user," my placeholder cell still shows a button from one of the previous cells in its place.

Anyone know how to truly clear cell data and display fresh cells?

Code - sorry messy

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *searchResultCell = @"searchResultCell";
    EIConnectionsGlobalSearchResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:searchResultCell];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[EIConnectionsGlobalSearchResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:searchResultCell];
    }
    
    //Create "no results" cell if datasource is empty after search
    if (_emptySearch == 1)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        cell.labelName.text = @"No results...";
        cell.labelConnectionStatus.text = @"Try another search.";
        cell.labelConnectionStatus.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        
        return cell;
    }
    else if (_emptySearch == 0)
    {
        //Assigning Search Result
        NSMutableDictionary *searchResult = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        //Text Configs
        cell.labelName.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"Name"];
        
        //Assign and Convert ConnectionStatus Number to string and color
        int connectionStatusInt = [[searchResult objectForKey:@"ConnectionStatus"] intValue];
        NSMutableArray *connectionStatus = [self connectionStatusToString:connectionStatusInt withIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.labelConnectionStatus.text = connectionStatus[0];
        cell.labelConnectionStatus.textColor = connectionStatus[1];
        
        //Setting up profile photo for cell
        if ([[searchResult objectForKey:@"picDownloaded"] isEqualToString:@"no"] || ![searchResult objectForKey:@"picDownloaded"]) {
            if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                [self startProfilePicDownload:searchResult andIndex:indexPath];
            }
            //Setting Default Image while downloading
            cell.imageView.image = defaultProfileImage;
        }
        else
        {
            //A profile pic exists in cache, so assign it to the view
            cell.imageView.image = [searchResult objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
        }
        
        //setting up cell actions
        UIButton *cellAction = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        cellAction.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 52, 18.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f);
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow-Icon"];
        [cellAction setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cellAction.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [cellAction setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cellAction addTarget:self action:@selector(showCellActionOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:cellAction];
        
        return cell;
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Most likely you are adding subviews that never get removed.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for looking - I've added my code

Comment: I think you're right though @rmaddy - I'm not explicitly removing the button or profile image from that cell. I just thought reloading a clear datasource would clear the cell. How do I go about removing those things before cell re-use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells get reused. This happens as the table view is scrolled as well as when it is reloaded.

One big issue you have is that you add another `UIButton` to a cell every time it is reused when `_emptySearch` is equal to 0. But the same cell can be reused under other conditions too.

You have a few choices.

1. Create two different custom cells. One for the rows needed when `_emptySearch` equals 0 and another for when it equals 1. In this case, add the button in IB instead of adding it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
2. Keep the code you have but you need to ensure you only add the button once and you also remove it for cells that don't need it.

Also look into the `UITableViewCell prepareForReuse` method. You should implement this method (and call `super prepareForReuse`) to reset cell labels and images as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll see if I can fix it with your advice